# If the interior of the boundary of a subset is empty, is the subset constructible?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. A subset $A \subset X$ is *sane* (a term I made up), if $i\partial A = \emptyset$, where $i$ denotes interior and $\partial$ boundary. A subset is [*locally closed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_closed_subset), if it is an intersection of an open subset and a closed subset. A subset is [*constructible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_set_(topology)), if it is a finite union of locally closed subsets.  An [*algebra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) over $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ which is closed under finite intersections, finite unions, and complement.

#### Problem

Is a sane subset constructible?

#### Background

I believe I have proved the following:

#### Theorem 1

Constructible subsets of $X$ form an algebra over $X$ which contains locally closed subsets.

#### Theorem 2

Sane subsets of $X$ form an algebra over $X$ which contains constructible subsets.

#### Theorem 3

The following are equivalent:

- $A$ is sane
- $i \overline{\partial A} = \emptyset$
- $\partial \partial A = \partial A$
- $\partial(iA \cup eA) = \partial A$
- $\partial A = \partial U$ for some $U \in \mathcal{T}$
- $\partial A \subset \partial U$ for some $U \in \mathcal{T}$

Here $i$ denotes interior and $e$ exterior, and all operations are with respect to $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with algebraic geometry so I would suggest removing that tag.

Comment: @CraniumClamp I included the algebraic geometry tag, because from what I know, constructible sets are used there.

Comment: @kaba What is the question? Are you asking to verify if the Theorems are true?

Comment: @0XLR No, the problem section is the question, the rest is background information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No:

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a topological space, $U$, $A$ be subsets of $X$. 
a) If $U$ is open in $X$, then $U$ is sane.  
b) If $U \subset A \subset \overline{U}$ and $U$ is sane, then $A$ is sane.

PROOF. a) Assume $x$ is in $V := i\partial U \subset \overline{U}$.
Then $\emptyset \neq V \cap U \subset (\overline{U} \setminus U) \cap U$. Contradicition. 
b) $\partial A = \overline{A} \setminus iA \subset \overline{U} \setminus iU$, hence
$i \partial A \subset i\partial U = \emptyset$.

Now let $U := \mathbb R \times (0, \infty) \subset \mathbb R^2$ with the usual topology, $A := U \cup (\mathbb Q \times \{0\})$.
Then, by the lemma, A is sane in $\mathbb R^2$.
Assume, $A$ is constructible. Then $\mathbb Q \times \{0\} = A \cap (\mathbb R \times \{0\})$ is constructible in $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$, hence $\mathbb Q$ is constructible in $\mathbb R$. Contradicition.